# jquery same ajax call kill

Tags: jquery, ajax, call, kill

I have ajax request

```
  result = $.ajax({
              url: '/live-sell-search.php?id=123',
              success: function(result) {
              $('.results-list').html(result);
                }
            });
```

I call this on change and I am trying to kill previous call if it is in progress with somthing like this

`if(result!='undefined'){resul.abort();}`

and several variations of this but it is always braking at some point. Can anyone tell me how this can be done?

Comment: Could you accept answers to your questions occasionally?

Comment: you should probably accept some of the answers on your previous questions...

Comment: @Niklas: +1 I like occassionally :)

Comment: @Naveen, up to 40% from 0% already, seems to be working :)

Comment: I didn't know there is a `kill` tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As other people have stated, you need to start accepting answers.

**Updated**

I use this on a website and it works quite well for me.

When the onChange event is called, it checks if there is already an AJAX call in affect. If so, it aborts it and starts a new AJAX call.

Once the AJAX call has completed the xhr variable gets nulled. Simple really.

```
var xhr = null;

$("#textbox").change(function(){

    if( xhr != null ) {
         xhr.abort();
    }

    xhr = $.ajax({
              url: '/live-sell-search.php?id=123',
              complete: function( xhr ){
                  xhr = null; // empty xhr object
              },
              success: function( data ) {
                  $('.results-list').html( data );
              }
          });
});
```

Comment: nope I have tried it  what I am looking for is may be some unique ID for call or using  jqXHR object or somthing like.

Comment: no but when I start click on chackboxes which trigger ajax on change it call it twice because I think last call is not started yet and the new one is call and I have two calls triggered. When I click slow it works. If you have any idea how can do this right I`d be very grateful. I tried to put var result=null; at the start of change function but again it breaks and it is freaking me out. I tried [ajaxmenager](http://www.protofunc.com/scripts/jquery/ajaxManager/)  plugin but it only can stop new call and keep the old till its finished.

Comment: Ahh right. I done a live search AJAX call before. I'll update my answer.